# How to correctly display foreign character read from a file?

Tags: c++, cout

I'm reading some text from a file (UTF-8 encoded) and storing it in a map, to evaluate how many times each word is contained in the file:

```
map<string, int> my_map;
ifstream f("file.txt");
string s;
while (f >> s)
{
    my_map[s]++;
}
```

And then I want to output the result using cout:

```
for (map<string,int>::const_iterator i = my_map.begin(); i != my_map.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->first << ": " << i->second << "\n";
}
```

The problem is, since my file contains some characters like ä and ö (it's written in Swedish) when I print the words most of them are displayed incorrectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale

Comment: I suspect the terminal that `cout` is connected to needs to be set to the same character encoding as the file the words are being read from, maybe `UTF-8`?

Comment: You cannot say *character string* without *character encoding*. There is no such thing as *plain text*.

Comment: Just edited the question: it's UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Have you tried using wstring and wcout?

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 encoding, like any text encoding, is a way to represent characters as a byte stream.  Your program is reading that byte stream and simply echoing it back out, so the problem with incorrect display is due to your terminal not being set to the correct encoding:  I tried your program on my terminal and it produced the expected output.

However, if you want to work with the strings that you read *as Unicode strings*, then `string` will not be sufficient, since it is simply a string of `char`, each of which contains one byte.  You should use `wstring`, which is a string of `wchar`, each of which is wide enough to store your Unicode character.  (This also means having to use `wcin`, `wcout`, and `wifstream`.)

But this still won't be enough:  you need to specify the *locale* to your streams in order to cause them to decode the UTF-8 byte stream into characters (and back from characters to UTF-8 again).  The relevant lines will look like the following.  Because you are reading Swedish, I set the locale to `sv_SE.UTF-8`, though other UTF-8 locales may be sufficient for your purposes:

```
#include <locale>
// ...
locale utf_8("sv_SE.UTF-8");
wcout.imbue(utf_8);
wifstream f("file.txt");
f.imbue(utf_8);
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't work in my machine. The statement `locale utf_8("sv_SE.UTF-8");` throws an exception that says "bad locale name".
Any ideas?

Comment: @JLagana: type `locale -a` on your machine and choose one of the locale strings listed there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "type `locale -a`" in my machine?

Comment: Type that command from your Terminal app, if on Mac OS X, or from any shell prompt on Linux. For Windows, try `systeminfo`.

Comment: I'm using Windows. Just ran systeminfo, the only info regarding locales that it gives me is about my system's locale and input locale; both of them are "pt-br;Português (Brasil)". Forgive my ignorance, but what am I looking for in here?